# Deprecated Version Errors When Deploying to PHP 8.0.29

Tags: php

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm encountering an issue when deploying my application on Vercel. I'm using PHP 8.0.29 in my project, and when attempting to deploy it on Vercel, I'm getting deprecated version errors that I hadn't experienced before. I would like to request your assistance in resolving this issue.

The specific errors I'm facing are as follows:

1. Deprecated: Return type of PhpOption\Some::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/task/user/vendor/phpoption/phpoption/src/PhpOption/Some.php on line 152
2. Deprecated: Return type of PhpOption\None::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/task/user/vendor/phpoption/phpoption/src/PhpOption/None.php on line 118

I've tried researching and modifying my code, but I haven't been able to resolve these issues yet. Can someone provide guidance on how to address these deprecated version errors in Vercel? Is there any specific configuration I should adjust in my project or on Vercel?

I would greatly appreciate your assistance and suggestions in resolving this issue. If you need more information or specific code snippets, please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: Presumably you need to update whatever package is providing the `PHPOption\None` class. Always run the same versions of PHP and packages in development and live.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the [phpoption](https://github.com/schmittjoh/php-option) library.

As stated [here](https://github.com/schmittjoh/php-option/issues/61), the deprecation warning on PHP 8 related to `Some::getIterator()` and `None::getIterator()` was fixed in version 1.8.0.